# Can anyone explain how ens resolver convert bytes memory to address type in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

when I am wangt to convert bytes memory to address, I often used the below function.

```
function bytesToAddress(bytes memory byte) public pure returns (address addr) {

        assembly {
             addr := mload(add(byte, 20))
       }
    }
```

But I found the ens public resolver has different code of writing

```
    function bytesToAddress(bytes memory b) internal pure returns(address payable a) {
    require(b.length == 20);
    assembly {
        a := div(mload(add(b, 32)), exp(256, 12))
    }
}
```

So why it add div and exp(256, 12),what actually happening .
`0x3E8Dc215A6E404A7Ba811DE5Da3ff2A809AE94E2`  is ens public resolver address in ropsten testnet.